# how to turn off spefic prettier rule for a specific file?

Tags: sorting, import, prettier

I'm using @trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports to sort my imports in the node.js application.
I need to turn off importOrder rule for specific files (I'm using jest.mock and I need to import some modules manualy).

how can I do this?

I have tried to override but it is not working
overrides: [
{
files:["src/services/lifeCycleEvent/**tests**/publishLifecycleEvent.test.ts","src/services/auth/**tests**/auth.test.ts"],
options: {
importOrder:["none"]

```
  }
}
```

]

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this package, but have you checked out the creator's Github discussion page? There might be someone there with more experience that could help you out.
https://github.com/trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports/discussions